# How to append jsx const in onclick with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

[How can i append the var varLogin to the div ???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwNQC.png)

Comment: pls open the img to see the code, it's kinda urgent

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Please replace the image in the question with a text-based [mcve].

Comment: Also, it's best not to mix react with jQuery as they will likely conflict with each other.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please use this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as a guideline on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using React the wrong way. You should have some state like this:

```
const [formVisible, setFormVisible] =  useState(false);
```

your varLogin should actually be VarLogin so a React Component.

Then inside you .divLogin div you would have something like this:

```
<div className="divLogin">

{formVisible && <VarLogin/>}

</div>
```

Then your login function should just be

```
const login = () => setFormVisible(true);
```

Comment: This is a good answer to a bad question. If this answer had no upvotes then the question is likely to be deleted.